# Android room autoincrement do not working

Tags: android, database, android-room

I try to integrate room in my project. I use standard room `autorGenerate = true` field bu it's not working. I add new object to db and then get from db. All fileds product_id is null somehow. All other fileds that I create on Product creation have values.It seems to me

```
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        public Integer object_id;
```

do not generate anything. Why so?

```
@Entity
public class Prodcut {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public Integer product_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_cloud")
    public Integer is_cloud;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    public Integer user_id;
    }
```

Comment: In most cases, it is recommended to use int instead on Integer. Do you really need Integer class?

Comment: Thank its helped

Comment: I added answer to prevent appearing in Unanswered tab. Please accept it.)

Comment: If you are using an Integer instead of int, and you don't want to change it, you can set product_id to null before inserting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use *int* instead of *Integer*.